# Cross platform installer for Qt

Tags: qt, open-source, installation, cross-platform

I'm trying to find a cross platform installer for small Qt applications.

It looks like the most popular (powerful ?) is [BitRock Install Builder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/qt-developers.html), but as the installer will be used in a school (I'm a teacher), I'm looking for a free/open source solution.

I'd like to generate an installer for a simple application on Windows, Mac and Linux OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Windows and Unix, use InstallJammer.

For Mac OS X, use the tool that comes with Qt itself: macdeployqt. Read about it in more detail [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/deployment-mac.html). This application will add all the required frameworks and build a DMG out of your app in one call from the console.

If you have any resource files (like images, or XML files etc) that you want to distribute with your application, compile them into your application directly with the [Qt resource system](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/resources.html). This will make it easier to distribute your app, on all platforms.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend NSIS. It's simple to use and it also integrates very well with CMake which would be very suitable as a build system for small applications.

Answer (score 2):

For windows i suggest:

1. NSIS - http://nsis.sourceforge.net
2. izPack - http://izpack.org/

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no installer for all platform.

For Windows and Unix, you can use [InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/).

For MacOSX you need to create a dmg image. This is very simple. Read the following web page for help : http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-DMG-File-on-a-Mac. By using apple script you can customize dmg (like an Application folder link into the dmg).

My preference for Win32 installer is [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).

Answer (score 0):

I have successfuly used [InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/) for Qt programs on Linux and Windows.

Comment: It looks like they stopped development around the time you wrote this. Can you tell me about your experience with it? Any pain-points to be mindful of, or cheat-sheets you can recommend?